# Wordpress - empty p tags

Tags: wordpress, tags

I am getting empty p tags that I cannot remove with jQ, nor can I see them in the source. They are being added by a mobile theme and can only be seen with the browser tool. I dont think jQ is adding them...

http://war-mobile.h2client.com/pillar/residential/?wpmp_switcher=mobile

Under the "We offer, right under the top white div border. I know how to solve the problem, as I did above, ([raw]) but I am curious why this is happening?

Comment: Without source we cant see where it goes wrong. Please upload some code so we can look in to it.

Comment: dont use extra p tag in code  wodpress editor automatically added p tag for the contant  part when you  press enter  or from starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your functions.php file in your theme:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_empty_p', 20, 1);
function remove_empty_p($content){
$content = force_balance_tags($content);
return preg_replace('#<p>\s*+(<br\s*/*>)?\s*</p>#i', '', $content);
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks for this. Question though -  i know this is an old thread. The last 2 parameters in the function the 20, 1. What do those do?