# Wordpress Creating Empty <p> Tags?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

It seems that wordpress is creating empty p tags for no reason whatso ever. I usually correct this problem by getting rid of all white space - as white space seems to be interpreted as "P TAG HERE! PLACE A P TAG HERE".

Here is my Wordpress dashboard content that I am concerned with:

```
[block]<p>This is a test</p>[/block]
```

As you can see there is no whitespace.

Here is the HTML Representation of that same piece of html.

```
<div class="block sidebar">
<p>This is a test</p>
<p></p></div>
```

See that second `<p></p>` that is there for no reason?

Can someone please tell me why this happens and how (if at all) I can remedy the situation?

I created that shortcode `[block]` as well and have been using it on other pages without this problem. So it seems page specific (because that makes sense..not).

Any help is very much appreciated. I can provide a link to the page if necessary. Let me know.

How the dashboard looks:

[image]

Comment: Wordpress just tries to add elements based on your input into the textbox. Just edit the raw HTML instead, you are not going to get the exact HTML you want by editing a version that parses text into HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The reason why wordpress does tried to format code is because of a function called wpautop**
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

I found a solution from this thread and tweaked it a bit: 
[Wordpress - empty p tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472531/wordpress-empty-p-tags)

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_empty_p', 11);
function remove_empty_p($content){
    $content = force_balance_tags($content);
    //return preg_replace('#<p>\s*+(<br\s*/*>)?\s*</p>#i', '', $content);
    return preg_replace('#<p></p>#i', '', $content);
}
```

The third parameter 11 is the priority. For me wpautop filter has a priority of 10 so I set my filter to 11 and that solved my problem.

Thanks all who have tried to help!

Comment: This worked for me - I am using the "Estatik" plugin with Elementor page builder. Enabling Estatik was causing empty <p></p> tags to appear after the closing of every element. This change to functions.php fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your functions.php and it will fix the problem

```
add_filter('the_content', 'shortcode_empty_paragraph_fix');
function shortcode_empty_paragraph_fix($content) {
    $array = array(
        '<p>['    => '[',
        ']</p>'   => ']',
        ']<br />' => ']',
        ']<br>'   => ']',
    );

    $content = strtr($content, $array);

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Will this possibly ruin other pages? What I mean is that this site is in production and has been for some time. I didn't build this - but rather I am redesigning specific pages. I am worried if I implement this - it may screw with other pages. Thoughts?

Comment: No it will work only if you have a shortcode and it replace the empty `p` with nothing :)

Comment: Nevermind - this will just get rid of empty <p> tags by the look of it. That is a clever work around - Thanks! Can you explain what this code does? To me - given this train of thought - a regex solution would work as well. The add_filter - is that a hook that gets called when the content is about to get rendered?

Comment: Question - If `<br>` tags are used in other pages as a formatting tool - will this strip those as well?? I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Sure, you can read more [here](http://www.wpexplorer.com/clean-up-wordpress-shortcode-formatting/) and [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12061)

Comment: I have used this on all my projects and it works like a charm without any other issues.

Comment: It seems that this is intended to remove <p> tags before and after a shortcode - that way you do not have a shortcode wraped by a <p> tag. Example - `<p>[shortcode]content[/shortcode]</p>` This is not my problem.